# IE9 cast context 'this' to Object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I've found out strange behavior in IE9. Lets say we have a function that return context:

```
function toContext() { return this; }
```

In IE9, if I call it with some primitive context, the context is casted to Object

```
toContext.call(3);  // => [object Number]
toContext.call(""); // => [object String]
```

In IE10 and later, it returns passed primitive, but IE9 gives this strange results, which spoils my coding pattern.

I emulate IE9 in IE11, maybe this is problem with a emulation. I searched for this behavior of old IE, but found nothing usefull. Can someone confirm that this behavior affects native IE9 or maybe someone know more about this topic?

Comment: Use strict mode to get the primitive, use sloppy mode to get it cast to an object. To cast a value to an object, don't use `getContext.call` but just `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IE9 does not support strict mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/strict-mode-javascript), which you seem to be using but is necessary to get primitive `this` values.

Comment: Console of all major browsers is not in strict mode (you can assign variable without declaring, you can declare reserved words, etc...) and still, all the browsers handles primitive `this` in console well. Also, I did not found any relation between context and strict mode. The article you provided just mentioned, that in strict mode, null context is not switched to global. I did not found any other consequences of strict mode on 'this'.

Comment: You might find [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript) more useful - in sloppy functions, `this` is cast to an object, which means becoming the global object for `null` and `undefined`, and boxing for other primitive values. This is exactly the behaviour you are experiencing.

Comment: I'm not getting primitive return values from your `toContext` function, in any browser or console I've tested, unless you defined `toContext` with strict mode.

Comment: sorry, I have `toContext()` declared in code in strict mode, and I've tested that function instead of declaring new one in console -- which I tested right now and you are right -- primitives are boxed in non-strict mode -- which is also mentioned in your second link to MDN. Thank you!